# Android DatePickerDialog weird TextView

Tags: android, date, datepicker, textview, datepickerdialog

I've discovered something strange:
Let's take a look at the normal `DatePickerDialog`:

[image: Without]

When I add this line which sets the maximum date on yesterday:

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(yesterdayCal.getTime().getTime());
```

It looks like this:

[image: with]

You see the difference? It adds a TextView above the DatePicker. I don't know why.
It looks weird and always shows the same date as selected. I want to remove it? Some ideas?

Full code:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        Calendar pickedCal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
                        pickedCal.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                        setToMidnight(pickedCal);

                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                        String pickedDate = dateFormat.format(pickedCal.getTime());
                        MyToast.showLong(LiveSelectActivity.this, getString(R.string.hinweis_nachtragen_gueltig, pickedDate));
                        startNachtragen(pickedCal.getTime());

                    }
                }, currentCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), currentCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                /*Setzt das maximale Auswahldatum auf gestern.*/
                Calendar yesterdayCal = (Calendar) currentCalendar.clone();
                yesterdayCal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(yesterdayCal.getTime().getTime());

                datePickerDialog.show();

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason setting the max date through this line sets the title of the `DatePickerDialog`

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(yesterdayCal.getTime().getTime());
```

In order to remove the title, use `setTitle("")`

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(yesterdayCal.getTime().getTime());
datePickerDialog.setTitle("");
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: it works! i will give you the bounty as soon as its unlocked!

Comment: Check this solution with older versions of Android. This might work just fine in modern versions, but older ones might need the title changed.